# has Google changed their OpenID discovery/points?

Tags: google-api, openid, single-sign-on

A system that uses Google OpenID to login has suddenly stopped working.
By suddenly I mean: there where no changes to server configurations. there where no code releases and what is more confusing, **is the same piece of code that talks to Googe servers, works fine from IPs which are our QA environment.**
The error I get is:

> Discovery failed: HTTP Request failed: Unable to Connect to
>   ssl://www.google.com:443. Error #101: Network is unreachable

Kind of not making sense to me that Google is down :-)

Answer (score 0):

Google's OpenID configuration is located here: https://accounts.google.com/.well-known/openid-configuration.

As per @Itay comment, there are deprecations on Google's use of OpenID technologies as per [Google+ Migration Timetable](https://developers.google.com/+/api/auth-migration#timetable).

That being said, the above end-points are based on the current [OAuth 2.0 Login](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login?hl=ko) from Google which uses OpenID Connect Discovery.

*NOT VERIFIED* If you want to use Google+ Sign In, the end points would need to change, per the [Migration from OAuth 2.0 guide](https://developers.google.com/+/api/auth-migration#userinfo) the URL is https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me/openIdConnect, but I think you would need to activate the Google+ API first to get this working.

Comment: By now, we learned Google is retiring their OpenID and move to OAuth

Comment: Actually from what I can tell OpenID connect runs on top of oauth 2.0